# How to prevent GridView saving data from build to build in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-ajax

I have a question regarding a situation that occurs with `GridView`, `ObjectDataSource` in ASP .NET application.

The `GridView` is linked to the `ObjectDataSource` and both are included within an `UpdatePanel` letting the GridView to fill in an asynchronous way from a form in the same page so it gets more rows as the user enters the data:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>    
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ReadOnly="True" 
                    SortExpression="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Periodicty" HeaderText="Periodicty" ReadOnly="True" 
                    SortExpression="Periodicty" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
            SelectMethod="GetSessionNames" TypeName="Simulation"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
        <asp:Label ID="Label27" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="NewWebSessionButton" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I start the project with Visual Studio 2008, fill the form and it works correctly. Then I stop the execution: rerun again and the data I entered in the previous run is in the `GridView`. Is like some sort of cache saved the data from the session before. I checked that `EnableCaching` property is set to false for the `ObjectDataSource`.

If I Rebuild Web Site in Visual Studio (not just Build) then it works corretly leaving the `GridView` empty.

Is this caused just becuase of Visual Studio? Can it be turned off? And will it happen in the final IIS it will run on?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked whether its your browser caching the page? I have had similar issues relating to this.

I ended up adding a little method to my base page to call to stop the page being cached.

eg:

```
/// <summary>
/// Set the page to not Cache
/// </summary>
protected void DontCache()
{
    try
    {
        //Dont Cache
        Response.Expires = 0;
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        Response.AppendHeader( "Pragma", "no-cache" );
    }
    catch ( Exception )
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```